# Adobe Air: Maintain canvas origin-clean flag when opening local files

Tags: canvas, air, html5-canvas

I'm trying to open a local image into a HTML5 canvas in Adobe Air and keep the origin-clean flag, so that I can use toDataURL. I have tried Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS), but it does not seem to be supported.  Does anyone know if there is away to maintain origin-clean flag and if so how to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't normally. Every file:/// URL has its own origin, so the origin-clean flag on the canvas is removed once you draw a local image, end of story.

...But there are flags that will allow you to in some browsers, for example, for Chrome:

`C:\Users\root\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files`

ought to do the trick.

Another way is to make a tiny web server to get around it.